# Fastest Python concurrency framework

Tags: python, c, performance, concurrency, event-handling

Could someone suggest a concurrency framework (threads, event based) in Python that can handle two tasks, one that has to process a LOT of events, and another that can process one or more commands at a slower rate? I am going to prototype with Twisted and see if it will meet my needs. I went through http://www.slideshare.net/dabeaz/an-introduction-to-python-concurrency which is informative and so the other choice I can try seems to be the multiprocessing module.

### Background

I am trying to write a program that can interface with a C program on one side and the network on the other. The C program generates events at a high rate (hundreds of thousands, possibly a million messages per second) which need to be consumed without letting it block, and the C program needs to be sent commands arriving from the network.

I think Python with zeromq (http://www.zeromq.org/) will suffice for consuming the events from the C program. But I need to also concurrently process commands from the network in my program. I have used Python with Twisted before to do asynchronous programming, but am not sure if it can handle the zeromq messages concurrently with other tasks fast enough.

I am going to try it out, but I was wondering if anybody has any thoughts on other ways of doing things. I would rather use Python as it would make handling of the commands and keeping state easier than if I had to do it in C.

Comment: I don't see how this question could result in a discussion consisting of anything other than speculation and/or hearsay.

Comment: Massive performance requirement, Python.  WTF?

Comment: @MartinJames zeromq with Python does seem to be able to process more than a million messages per second. But I also need the Python program (if I choose Python) to process network events concurrently. My question is what technique in Python should I be using. You think I should write the whole thing in C?

Comment: Okay, I guess I will edit this to become something more concrete and maybe somebody can help me.